# Passing an async function to beforeEach - Mocha

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

I have to make the argument to beforeEach, async because I'm calling clearCaches() within it
Problem is, I get a warning saying *DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.*

I think it's because the argument passed to beforeEach is being called again and again, without a callback. Does someone know how to fix this ?

```
    beforeEach( async function () {
    Log.test(`BeforeTest: ${this.currentTest.title}`);
    // Clear caches directory
    await clearCaches();
});
```

Comment: New Mocha should do fine if you return a promise. What version are you on?

Comment: I'm at 5.2.0 (when I ran mocha --version) though my package.json file says 4.0.1

Comment: Make sure locally installed mocha and @types/mocha packages are up to date

Comment: This should work, they even have [this example](https://mochajs.org/#using-async-await).

Comment: Could you tell me which version of @types/mocha and mocha are required min ? I'm doing this for an academic project and I have to use the version given i.e

"@types/mocha": "2.2.44"
"mocha":                4.0.1

Comment: It is working, it's just that I get a warning "DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated."